# Can't find the infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm working on an assignment for class and I'm getting an infinite loop in my code somewhere. I've been staring at it for a day and even tried to get help from my professor (He was out). I've tried debugging but I get lost midway through. A fresh set of eyes would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code I can provide more if necessary.

```
while (numRequests != 0 || allocated.size() != 0) {

        for(int k = 0; k < allocated.size(); k++) {
            allocated.get(k).decreaseTime();
            if (allocated.get(k).equals(0)) {
                memory.deallocate(allocated.get(k).getId());
                startPoint -= allocated.get(k).getSize();
                allocated.remove(k);
                k--;
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < pr.length; i++) {
            if (pr[i] != null) {
                String requestSize = pr[i].substring(0, pr[i].indexOf(","));
                int rSize = Integer.parseInt(requestSize);
                String requestTime = pr[i].substring(pr[i].indexOf(",") + 1);
                int rTime = Integer.parseInt(requestTime);
                int bSize = 0;
                if (rSize <= 1024) {
                    bSize = 1024;
                    if (rSize <= 512) {
                        bSize = 512;
                        if (rSize <= 256) {
                            bSize = 256;
                            if (rSize <= 128) {
                                bSize = 128;
                                if (rSize <= 64) {
                                    bSize = 64;
                                    if (rSize <= 32) {
                                        bSize = 32;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (bSize <= (1024 - startPoint)) {
                        pr[i] = null;
                        numRequests--;
                        allocatedMemory am = new allocatedMemory(i+1, bSize, rTime);
                        allocated.add(am);
                        memory.allocate(i+1, rTime, startPoint, bSize);
                        startPoint += bSize;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

I'm not asking for help finishing the assignment. I feel like I need to do that myself. I'm just really stuck here for some reason and could use a nudge in the right direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Language? This looks like it could be Java or C/C++.

Comment: Are you sure you need OR in those while conditions?

Comment: @GreenMatt it is java

Comment: @Shomz Yes I need them. The loop is only supposed to end when there area no more requests and allocated is empty.

Comment: Yes, but read my answer... could it happen that one of them goes to -1 and the other is 0 at that point? If so, the loop will continue, your loop breaks only if *both* of them are zero.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use AND (&&) in your while condition part, or change it to something like

```
while (numRequests > 0 || allocated.size() > 0) {
```

This will break the loop once the BOTH of them drop to zero or below.

Your original condition will break only if they BOTH are equal to zero in an iteration (which may or may not happen).

Comment: A good suggestion I went and changed that but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Why don't you do some debugging and print output after every iteration? Make a simple test case and use `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: Ok I can try that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. I just skimmed through your code so I might've missed something, but that while loop looked suspicious right away.

Comment: The prints were a good idea. The problem appears to be the for loops actually. It successfully processes the first request but after that it won't enter either for loop so numRequests and allocated.size() don't change. Now to figure out why.

Comment: Same principle, start with a small test case.

Comment: For anyone else who looks at this the problem was that I used .equals(0) instead of == 0 inside my first for loop.